# ¿Como configurar apache con virtual host y ssl?

Tags: nodejs, apache, ssl, virtualhost, vps

Tengo una landing en wordpress en un vps que tiene este archivo de configuracion apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName landing.com.co
    ServerAlias www.landing.com.co
    Redirect permanent / https://landing.com.co/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName landing.com.co
    ServerAlias www.landing.com.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/landing.com.co/html

    Protocols h2 http:/1.1

    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.landing.com.co'">
        Redirect permanent / https://landing.com.co/
    </If>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/landing.com.co-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/landing.com.co-access.log combined

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/landing.com.co-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/landing.com.co-0001/privkey.pem
    SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem"

    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCompression off
    SSLUseStapling on

    <Directory /var/www/landing.com.co/html/>
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/landing.com.co/html/>
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [PT,L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Y necesito correr una app hecha en node con el mismo certificado ssl o sin el, pero lo que esta sucediendo es que al entrar a **app.landing.com.co** me redirigue a **landing.com.co**.

Esta es la configuracion apache de la app

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>

    ServerName app.landing.com.co
    ServerAlias app.landing.com.co
    Redirect permanent / https://app.landing.com.co
</VirtualHost>
#Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app.landing.com.co
    ServerAlias app.landing.com.co

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/landing.com.co-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/landing.com.co-0001/privkey.pem
    SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem"

    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCompression off
    SSLUseStapling on


    # This is needed only if you want to use web sockets
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8000/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```